# Clang parameter -Wno-conditional-type-mismatch and GCC

Tags: c, gcc, parameters, clang

The following simple C example program correctly emits a compile warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *p = NULL;
    int q = 1;

    if(1 == 2 ? p : q) { printf("Info\n"); }
    return(0);
}
```

The warning emitted is "warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression".

In clang, the parameter "-Wno-conditional-type-mismatch" works in such a way that no warnings appear for the example code.

In GCC, I was looking for a similar option. The best I could find was the parameter "-fcond-mismatch", which would allow the example code. From the man page:

> Allow conditional expressions with mismatched types in the second and third arguments.  The
> value of such an expression is void.  This option is not supported for C++.

But when using this option, GCC keeps complaining:

```
# gcc -fcond-mismatch -c example.c
example.c: In function 'main':
example.c:8:17: warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression
    8 |     if(1 == 2 ? p : q) { printf("Info\n"); }
```

Using GCC 10.3.0, would there be a GCC option or compiler flag to suppress the warning, in a similar way as clang does?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: GCC's manual says "The warning message for each controllable warning includes the option that controls the warning."  Since this message does not include such an option, this suggests it is not controllable.

Comment: If `-fcond-mismatch` really applied here and did what it said, then the code should fail to compile even harder, since then you would be using a `void` expression as the test of your `if`.

Comment: Why not just apply an appropriate cast?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: of course, casting would work in this particular example program. I also have a situation where the ternary function arguments contain functions calls, one returning a void* and one is a plain void(), which I cannot cast.

Comment: It's not clear what parts of this code are representative and what parts are simplifications, and what parts you can change and what parts you can't. Is `1==2` a compile-time constant and you'd like the compiler to completely ignore the operand of the ternary conditional operator that isn't taken? Can you change the code to `1 == 2 ? p != 0 : q != 0`? And “one is a plain void()”: that wouldn't make any sense as a conditional.

Comment: Can you update your question to be a little more realistic and representative of your actual problem?

Comment: My question is simply: using GCC 10.3.0, would there be a GCC option or compiler flag to suppress the warning, in a similar way as clang does? The code is just an illustration. I guess @NateEldredge answered it already.

Comment: Re: *" I also have a situation where the ternary function arguments contain functions calls, one returning a void * and one is a plain void(), which I cannot cast."* that suggests that the ternary operator is not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such flag.  [GCC's manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) says, under `-Werror=`,  "The warning message for each controllable warning includes the option that controls the warning."

Since this message does not mention such an option, this suggests it is not controllable.